# vuetify 2.0 v-data-table loading prop not disabling after loading

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

In my app I am using Vuetify 2.0s v-data-table to display a table of data. I am trying to implement a loading linear-progress-bar while waiting for my elements to load. I am following the [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables) , and when I add the props `loading` and `loading-text="bla"`, it shows the loading text and linear-progress-bar, but after the elements load in the linear-progress-bar does not go away.

I have tried setting `loading="elements"`, which then only shows the loading text and not the linear progress bar. I have also tried `:loading="elements"` which disables the entire loading feature.

```
<v-data-table
  :items="elements"
  :headers="elementsHeaders"
  :search="elementsSearch"
  hide-default-footer
  loading
  loading-text="Laden... even geduld aub"
>
```

I expect that with that code, when elements are loaded in that both the linear progress bar and loading text goes away.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use a boolean variable with the `loading` prop (add it to your component `data`).

```js
data() {
   return {
      myloadingvariable: false
   }
}
```

Set it to `true` before starting loading data and to `false` when data have been loaded.

```html
<v-data-table :loading="myloadingvariable" loading-text="Laden... even geduld aub">
```

Comment: `elements` is a computed property, so I could set the loading variable to true before that, but then it returns `this.elements`, so not sure where to set it back to false.

Comment: How do you load data? Isn't it http request? Could you please share the code of the computed property?

Answer (score 4):

Here is my solution

```html
<v-data-table
  :items="elements"
  :headers="elementsHeaders"
  :search="elementsSearch"
  hide-default-footer
  :loading="loadTable"
  loading-text="Laden... even geduld aub"
>
```

```js
data() {
   return {
    loadTable: true
   }
}

methods: {
  async listar() {
    const res = await axios.get('/especies');
    this.items = res.data;
    this.loadTable= false;
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old topic, but I was searching for same thing just now.

Simply solved it using

```
:loading="!items.length"
```

Comment: That's ok, but you must be sure that your http request always returns at least one element

Comment: it doesnt work when you dont have any data in your list . actulayy when your list is empty